# Can VLC output video through HDMI adapter to TV on first gen iPad?

Tags: ipad, video

I have videos on the iPad that can be played back by VLC.
But the only output I get when connected to the TV is sound, no video.

Is there any way to get them to play through the HDMI using VLC, or alternatively move them to Cinemax without connecting to a PC and iTunes

Answer (score 2):

According to [Apple's documentation](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4108), the AV Adapter for iOS supports mirroring only on the iPad 2. On the iPad and iPhone, video out has to be supported by the app itself, whether Apple designed it (YouTube) or a third party app (Netflix, Hulu).

Because VLC for iOS hasn't been updated in quite a while (indeed its no longer available on the App Store for legal reasons), I wouldn't be surprised that the VLC app just does not support video out, although I don't know for sure if that's the case.

There is recourse if you jailbreak, [DisplayOut](http://rpetri.ch/cydia/displayout/), which enables mirroring on VGA, HDMI, component, or composite outputs for the original iPad, iPhone, and fourth gen iPod Touch. If you are able to install this you would then be able to output VLC on your iPad via the HDMI adapter.

Comment: Ben since posting my answer I've purchased the HDMI adapter myself and can confirm that on iPhone 4 any app that doesn't support mirroring can be enabled by jailbreaking and installing DisplayOut.

Comment: Per your flag, admins do not have the ability to accept answers on the behalf of users that appear to have abandoned a question. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to need to do it with VLC, you will need a jailbreak. If jailbreaking is not an option i would transfer the videos from your ipad onto your mac and watch them in Front Row

Comment: It's not critical it seems Cinexplayer will play movies out through the hdmi. It's a pity as don't have access to a pc to transfer the movies from vlc to cine player. Went away for Easter thinking I could use the big tv..... wish there was a filemanager utility that you could use to move files around on the iPad, without a pc.

Comment: There is... if you jailbreak, check out iFile.